# Proposal: "please-fix-tags" tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

I have run into a few cases where I don't know the correct grammatical terms for the types of words or parts of a sentence I am asking about.  One such example is my question [How to call attention to "I" without "I myself" or the pretentious "even I"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21786/how-to-call-attention-to-i-without-i-myself-or-the-pretentious-even-i)

I would like to add a comment or a note that indicates to other users who do know that they should feel welcome *and* encouraged to add appropriate tags, though I don't want to create a cleanup burden.

One way to do this would be a new tag: **please-fix-tags** tag (or something similar).  This tag could be perused by minds immeasurably superior to mine to correctly tag questions where the poster wasn't quite sure what tags and terms even apply to their question.

Answer (score 2):

This is a so-called "meta" tag, which are strongly discouraged across the entire network. (See the [blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).)

If you are not sure which tags to use, just leave a comment to that extent, or drop by in our [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-and-usage).

Comment: Yes, and I usually agree.  I see a slight difference though, which is that this one is not persistent and will disappear after it's been taken care of.  A comment would leave lasting noise (until the owner or a moderator drops by).  In addition, it is useful on it's own, unlike the tags that Aaronaught posted about.

Comment: @Renesis: I see your point, but let me assure you that a) the tag would get killed with fire by the powers that be and b) if you @-mention me in chat, I *will* look into it, but I can't promise to babysit any particular tag 24/7. Most importantly, we don't want to provide an easy cop-out. There is a good reason why questions without tags are not allowed. Surely people can be expected to think of at least *one* meaningful tag for their questions. [please-fix-tags] would be circumventing the system. Soon enough, every second question would get tagged with that tag and that tag alone.

Comment: I didn't think about the 1-tag requirement.  This would certainly torpedo that.  However, I was more hoping that I could entice someone to add *more* tags since I couldn't think of any more than one meaningful tag.

Answer (score 0):

SE sites are Wiki-style sites; everybody with the right reputation can edit questions, and answers. Tagging a question for being edited is probably useless, as somebody who notes a clear typo (or the usage of a non grammatically correct phrase) will probably edit the question/answer.

In the case the meaning is not clear, and who can edit the answer/question is not able to understand what the OP was trying to say, then s/he will leave a comment, asking what the OP was trying to say.